# How to fix my TableLayout and TableRow into specific positions dynamically?

Tags: java, android, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm having problems setting up my TableRow with some TextViews in TableLayout dynamically. I have two pictures, one is my current situation shown, and the other is my mockup, expected situation (the goal which I need to achieve). I do not have any XML layouts; All of these are created programmatically, which is also something I need to achieve.

The snapshots shown are for a High Score screen, where I get a list of players with high scores, and display them altogether in a TableLayout. I'm just having trouble with the row/column positions.

[image: nothing]

Here's my code:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //=============================================
    TextView number = new TextView(this);
    number.setText("1");
    TextView place = new TextView(this);
    place.setText("4th");
    TextView testScore = new TextView(this);
    testScore.setText("113489");
    table = new TableLayout(this);
    //rows = new Stack<TableRow>();
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.addView(number);
    row.addView(place);
    row.addView(testScore);
    table.addView(row);
    this.setContentView(table);
}
```

If anyone knows how I should change my code from the Current Situation to the mockup Expected Situation, I gladly appreciate it. If I'm doing something wrong, please post a comment. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a good link about TableLayout and TableRow, creating specific positions dynamically. [Link is here.](http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/dynamic-tablelayout-in-android/) Of course, the code here is just the barebones of it, used to demostrate a simple position layout.

Here's my code and the given picture of the result:

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();



        //=============================================

        dip = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (float) 1, this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        if (dip <= 0)
            dip = 1;


        TextView number = new TextView(this);
        TextView place = new TextView(this);
        TextView testScore = new TextView(this);


        number.setText("1");
        place.setText("4th");
        testScore.setText("113489");

        number.setWidth(50 * dip);
        place.setWidth(75 * dip);
        testScore.setWidth(150 * dip);

        number.setPadding(20*dip, 0, 0, 0);

        table = new TableLayout(this);
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.addView(number);
        row.addView(place);
        row.addView(testScore);
        table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        this.setContentView(table);
    }
```

I'm actually astonished that there's a method for obtaining the DIP unit. Should've searched for that in the first place. :P

[image: nothing]

Answer (score 0):

Set the layout weight of each textview to 1 and the layout width to 0dp.  That will cause them to split the available space equally.  You could use layout gravity left, center and right as appropriate to further ensure maximum separation.

Comment: TextView.setLayoutParams() uses ViewGroup.LayoutParams(), which I don't know what parameters of what subclass should I use. Do you know?